# Font size of title property of TitleWindow component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, font-size

How can I set font size of title property (header) in TitleWindow component?

If I use fontSize property, it sets the font size for all components in TitleWindow, which is not what I want. I only want to set it for the title.

I'm using **Flex 3**

Thank you

Comment: any specific reason for not using flex 4 ??

Comment: legacy code, will switch at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the title-style-name css attribute, and then assign the font size in a block that uses that css class name.

```
TitleWindow
{
    title-style-name: "myTitle";
}

.myTitle
{
   font-size: 16;
}
```

Comment: If I set an extra class in my css file and then specify font size in that css class and then set style name of `TitleWindow` component to this css class, title font size will be changed as well as the rest of the components in the `TitleWindow`. I only wanted the title to be of different font size (not all text in the component)

Comment: @Dragan Chupacabric You should set the style name of the window title, not the window itself. I've updated the answer to show the syntax for this in css.